# how to make two mat-form-field inputs stay inside the parent div without extrapolating?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

I'm trying to make two "mat-form-field" side by side and not break the parent div.

[image: here is the case]

And, here is the code:

```
<div class="flex gap">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
    <mat-label>Latitude</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="latitude" />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
    <mat-label>Longitude</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="longitude" />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gap {
  gap: 24px;
}
```

I already tried to put "box-sizing: border-box", but I was not successful

Comment: What to do you mean `extrapolating` the parent `div`? Also, what does it mean in your context, "breaking the parent element" ?

Comment: it's looks like work (always you define .flex, and w-100 class in the .css), see a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-screxq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.css) with your code